# node doesn't recognized new enviroment variable in command line

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

Trying to insert a variable through command line, I got an unexpected error.

```
MY_VARIABLE=198165rgespoj65af npm run server

MY_VARIABLE is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: if u want to set an environment variable then u need to use `set` command.

Comment: I only want to use this variable in this specific process

Comment: `set MY_VARIABLE=198165rgespoj65af && npm run server` ?

Comment: it worked, thanks ;)